Problem with deserialized classes with Visual Studio
This is my first experience with the deserializer.
I'm working on an Xml file, which I don't publish because it's too large, using Visual Studio's 2019 Paste Special to create the classes.
However, a strange thing happens, all the classes that have this type of tag:
<value xsi:type="CD" code="60975-0" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Displayed Name"/>
The property type is not deserialized and, therefore, is not visible in the class. I don't understand the reason for this behavior, but anyway I inserted the missing code for the type attribute.
 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type
    {
        get
        { return this.typeField; }
        set
        { this.typeField = value; }
    }


But I can't insert the xsi: prefix before type.
I looked at these links
How to add xsi:type attribute to an XML element
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/835371/Create-XML-Node-with-attribute-xsi-type
But, with my little experience, I couldn't figure out how to fix the problem.
I tried replacing this:
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]

with this:
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xsi:type")]

but receive this error:
InvalidOperationException: 'xsi:type' contains an invalid character for a name.

xsi is a namespace, not part of the name. All XML elements and attributes have a name. The document may specify a default namespace with xmlns="....that...namespace" in which case elements in that namespace don't need a prefix. You could use [XmlAttribute (Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")] BUT ...

xsi isn't a random namespace, it's typically used in XML Schema documents, files that specify what the contents of a specific type of XML document would be. You don't find it actual data documents. Are you trying to deserialize HL7 documents?

@Panagiotis Kanavos, Yes it is an HL7 document and in the file header I have: xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", I don't know if this can be useful

You need an inherited class using XMLInclude : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=net-8.0  "value" is the Base Class and "CD" is the inherited class.

I found the solution, in the classes where it is needed just add this line:
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type",Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]

Thank you all
